# can not get value from radio button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I try to get value from radio button, here's my code:

```
var isactive = result.IsActive;
            $("input[name='RadioActive']").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == isactive) {
                    $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                }
            });
```

and the html :

```
<section class="col col-lg-2">
    <label class="label">Active</label>
         <div class="inline-group">
            <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="RadioActive" class="RadioActive" value="T" />
                 <i></i>
                 Yes
            </label>
            <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="RadioActive" class="RadioActive" value="F" />
                 <i></i>
                  No
            </label>
         </div>
</section>
```

Doesn't work. Do you have any Idea ? What am I Missing ?

Comment: From where are you getting the `result` in the first line of your js code?

Comment: What is `result.IsActive`? When and how is the code executed? Use [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the   result.IsActive   I get from My Controller method that call My model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `result.IsActive` isn't resolving. Simply setting `isactive` to either `T` or `F` will check the radio button for you:

```js
var isactive = "T";
$("input[name='RadioActive']").each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == isactive) {
    $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="col col-lg-2">
  <label class="label">Active</label>
  <div class="inline-group">
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="RadioActive" class="RadioActive" value="T" />
      Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="RadioActive" class="RadioActive" value="F" />
      No
    </label>
  </div>
</section>
```

Note that setting it to `true` or `false` will **not** trigger the `checked` attribute; it needs to equal the `value` of the radio button exactly (which are `T` and `F` respectively).

Ensure that your `result.IsActive` returns either `T` or `F`, and it will work correctly for you.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: yes, you are right, that   'result.IsActive' is return null,.. i will fix this first,, thanx for you all..

Answer (score 1):

To select a radio button using jquery use [**prop**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

In the below snippet expecting the value of `result.IsActive` to be `F` & assigning it to `isactive`

```js
var isactive = "F";
$("input[name='RadioActive']").each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == isactive) {
    $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="col col-lg-2">
  <label class="label">Active</label>
  <div class="inline-group">
    <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="RadioActive" class="RadioActive" value="T" />
                 <i></i>
                 Yes
            </label>
    <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="RadioActive" class="RadioActive" value="F" />
                 <i></i>
                  No
            </label>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var isActive='F';

$("input[name='RadioActive']").each(function (index,value) {
               if( $(value).val()==isActive)
                $(value).attr('checked','checked');
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="col col-lg-2">
    <label class="label">Active</label>
         <div class="inline-group">
            <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="RadioActive" class="RadioActive" value="T" />
                 <i></i>
                 Yes
            </label>
            <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio"  name="RadioActive" class="RadioActive" value="F" />
                 <i></i>
                  No
            </label>
         </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
$("input[name='RadioActive']:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your JavaScript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myForm').on('click', function () {
            var value = $("[name=RadioActive]:checked").val();
            alert("Selected Radio Value is :  " + value);
        })
    });
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <section class="col col-lg-2">
          <label class="label">Active</label>
               <div class="inline-group">
                  <label class="radio">
                       <input type="radio" name="RadioActive" class="RadioActive" value="T" />
                       <i></i>
                       Yes
                  </label>
                  <label class="radio">
                       <input type="radio" name="RadioActive" class="RadioActive" value="F" />
                       <i></i>
                        No
                  </label>
               </div>
      </section>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is a working plunker for the code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/D9UaU43OxHGUg80xxsiS?p=preview